# No se encuentra el metodo dentro del objeto

Tags: php, poo

estoy haciendo una clase **Conexion.php** donde tengo la conexion, y la clase  **UsuarioHandler.php**  donde me encargo de hacer todas las query que necesite relacionadas con usuario.

**Conexion.php**

```
<?php 

class Conexion {

    private $hostname;
    private $db;
    private $user;
    private $password ;

    private $connection;


    function __construct(){
        $this->hostname = "localhost";
        $this->db = "tb_crud";
        $this->user = "root";
        $this->password= "";
        $this->connection = null;
    }



    public function conectar(){
        if ($this->connection == null) {
            $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->user, $this->password);
            mysqli_select_db($this->connection,$this->db);
            return $this->connection;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }

    }

    public function desconectar(){
        if ($connection != null) {
            $connection = null;
        }
    }

    public function getConnection(){
        return $this->connection;
    }   
}


 ?>
```

**UsuarioHandler.php**

```
<?php 
    include_once 'Conexion.php';

    class UsuarioHandler{

        private $conexion = null;

        public function __construct(){

            $this->conexion = new Conexion();    
        }


        public function mostrarTodos(){
            $this->conexion->conectar();

            if ($this->conexion != null) {

                $result = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
                $result->execute();

                var_dump($result);

                return $result;
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }

        }
    }


     $qhu = new UsuarioHandler();

    $qhu->mostrarTodos();



 ?>
```

Si se fijan en el fichero **UsuarioHandler.php** tengo debaje de la clase esto:

```
$qhu = new UsuarioHandler();

        $qhu->mostrarTodos();
```

espara probar que funcione pero me esta arrojando **unos errores** :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Conexion::prepare() in...


Call to undefined method Conexion::prepare()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu clase conexion no contiene el metodo prepare.

Ese metodo, es propio del objeto conexion a la base de datos, mas no de tu clase.

Tenes una función que devuelve tu objeto conexion, el que se conecta a la base de datos y estas definido como `private $connection;`, ese es sobre el cual podes hacer prepare...

Asi que tus opciones son:

- trabajar sobre tu clase para generar mas metodos dentro de ella.

Como por ejemplo:

```
    <?php 

    class Conexion {
    ......
    public function getEjecutarQuery($sql){ return $this->conexion->prepare($sql); }   

    .....
    }

 ?>
```

O

- Devolver la conexion a tu otra clase, y usarla desde ahi

Para esto ultimo, podrias hacer:

```
$miConexion = $this->conexion->getConnection();
$result = $miConexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
```